# Why EC2 new instance is created when I try to terminate it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-devops

Good morning,
I had a free tier EC2 instance, now I want to stop it and delete it. The problem is that when I am trying to terminate running EC2 Instance, then AWS terminates it but it creates new one (same as terminated). How can I fully terminate and delete AWS EC2 instance?

[image]

As you can see it should delete on termination: [image]

Comment: Did you set up an autoscaling group?

Comment: You have an auto-scaling group setup. Or possibly the instance was created and managed by Elastic Beanstalk or the ECS or EKS services, so they are replacing it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "Delete on Termination" flag is for the volume attached to the instance which indicates whether you want to keep the storage after terminating your ec2-instance.

The only way I think of here is where the ec2-server is attached to auto-scaling group with min =1, you need to check the auto-scaling group and decrease the min to : 0

Answer (score 0):

If there's an Auto Scaling Group associated with your instance, you may need to disable or delete it. This prevents the Auto Scaling Group from launching new instances.

Instances can be replaced if CloudWatch Alarms are triggering an Auto Scaling action. Check if there are any CloudWatch Alarms associated with your Auto Scaling Group and update/delete them if needed.

AWS CloudTrail provides a record of actions taken by a user, role, or an AWS service in your account. Review the CloudTrail logs to see if there are any events related to the replacement of your instance.